# Should I use singleton?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I am writing a C++ program that can read and process info of a ext2 filesystem. I figured that I should create a class named `Device` that will hold the file descriptor of the device and provide a method for reading from the device. An instance of this class should be instantiated once in the beginning of the program and used across multiple classes, e.g. `BlockGroup`, `SuperBlock`, etc.

Logically I shouldn't have more then one instance of this `Device` class, and that's a pro to use singleton. But I wonder: What risk am I taking if i don't use singleton, and just make sure that I create only one instance of this class across my application?

Comment: What do you do if your system as more then one ext2 filesystem (device in your terminology) and you want to process both ?

Comment: My program handles one file system at a time. A device is a partition for that matter

Comment: Whether something should be described as a singleton has to be decided based on if it would potentially make sense to have more then one instance of a class and not one if your application currently would only use one.

Comment: Singletons make the code hard to test. Singletons are generally considered an antipattern think long and hard before you use it. If you do decide you need it then combine it with a creator pattern so that you can create mock versions of your singletons when testing.

Comment: But even if only one instance would be valid, a singleton pattern has many downsides (controllability of lifetime, unit testing, …). Throwing an error if more more the one instance of the class exits at the same time could be a better solution.

Comment: [Cppcon20:Peter Muldoon on retiring the singleton pattern](https://youtu.be/K5c7uvWe_hw)